# How to add GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW in Eclipse IDE to address Valgrind string leak?

Tags: c++, eclipse, memory-leaks, valgrind

Sorry this is a stupid question. I've recently run valgrind on an executable to look for memory leaks. In the valgrind memory leak report, it shows the following as a possibly lost:

```
==20425== 64 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 520 of 580
==20425==    at 0x4029FDE: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:313)
==20425==    by 0x415F213: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==20425==    by 0x4161125: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==20425==    by 0x41617AF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==20425==    by 0x804B805: test() (MyApp.cpp:228)
```

After reading through stack overflow, it seems that this "string" error report is caused by a memory pool optimization and valgrind does not like it. Its been suggested to use GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW to fix it. How can I configure Eclipse IDE to use this during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Try a recent valgrind (3.9.0 or the last SVN version) and see
if 
  valgrind --leak-check-heuristics=stdstring your_program
solves the possibly lost
(note that there are other heuristics helping for c++.
Use --leak-check-heuristics=all to activate them all)